# App Script last row getting issue new to GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am working on a sheet which contains data base , and i have copy one script that every time user submits any data its makes pdf out of that line with the help of script. its works smooth but the issue is when ever i run the script its start again from row 1, and makes again duplicate pdfs . so my request to all pls help me i want only its should fetch the last row which is new. and don't it start from the first row here is the code please help me .

```
function billPdf() {
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("17Wyo_wHI1p_zNrEQWnay7pbb_3WS8Sivw");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1CiEPOh7X82M5jpupYtYqBdnlYIzlSRCjb");
const tempDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1IZr8ovAMOV1z2ADfXHjKvvHNOzMSW1T4WwC0XPd7_OeQ");
const currentSheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TT");  
const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,73).getDisplayValues();
  let errors =[];
  data.forEach(row => {
  try{
  createPdf(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[13],row[14],row[15],row[16],row[17],row[23],row[24],row[25],row[26],row[27],row[33],row[34],row[35],row[36],row[37],row[43],row[44],row[45],row[46],row[47],row[49],row[69],row[11],pdfFolder,tempFolder,tempDoc,row[0]);
  errors.push["Done"];
 } catch(err){
 errors.push(["Failed"]);
  }
});
   currentSheet.getRange(2, 71,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).setValue(errors);
}
function createPdf(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,aa,ab,ac,pdfFolder,tempFolder,tempDoc,pdfname) {
const newtemplateFile = tempDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newtemplateFile.getId());
const body = openDoc.getBody();
const currentSheet1 =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TT");  
body.replaceText("{invoice}", a);
body.replaceText("{date}", b);
body.replaceText("{type}", c);
body.replaceText("{contact}", d);
body.replaceText("{name}", e);
body.replaceText("{email}", f);
body.replaceText("{p1}", g);
body.replaceText("{p2}", h);
body.replaceText("{p3}", i);
body.replaceText("{p4}", j);
body.replaceText("{p5}", k);
body.replaceText("{q1}", l);
body.replaceText("{q2}", m);
body.replaceText("{q3}", n);
body.replaceText("{q4}", o);
body.replaceText("{q5}", p);
body.replaceText("{mr1}", q);
body.replaceText("{mr2}", r);
body.replaceText("{mr3}", s);
body.replaceText("{mr4}", t);
body.replaceText("{mr5}", u);
body.replaceText("{to1}", v);
body.replaceText("{to2}", w);
body.replaceText("{to3}", x);
body.replaceText("{to4}", y);
body.replaceText("{to5}", z);
body.replaceText("{subt}", aa);
body.replaceText("{add}", ab);
body.replaceText("{foe}", ac);
openDoc.saveAndClose();
const bolbPDF = newtemplateFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(bolbPDF).setName(pdfname);
tempFolder.removeFile(newtemplateFile);
return pdfFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the last row of the sheet "TT" and use the values to the function "createPdf".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,73).getDisplayValues();
let errors = [];
data.forEach(row => {
  try {
    createPdf(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27], row[33], row[34], row[35], row[36], row[37], row[43], row[44], row[45], row[46], row[47], row[49], row[69], row[11], pdfFolder, tempFolder, tempDoc, row[0]);
    errors.push["Done"];
  } catch (err) {
    errors.push(["Failed"]);
  }
});
currentSheet.getRange(2, 71, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).setValue(errors);
```

#### To:

```js
const row = currentSheet.getRange(currentSheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 73).getDisplayValues()[0];
let error = "";
try {
  createPdf(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[13],row[14],row[15],row[16],row[17],row[23],row[24],row[25],row[26],row[27],row[33],row[34],row[35],row[36],row[37],row[43],row[44],row[45],row[46],row[47],row[49],row[69],row[11],pdfFolder,tempFolder,tempDoc,row[0]);
  error = "Done";
} catch (err) {
  error = "Failed";
}
currentSheet.getRange(currentSheet.getLastRow(), 71).setValue(error);
```

- `data` is the last row of sheet "TT". The values of the row are used for the function `createPdf`.

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering in my following script every thing is fine, but problem is when i try to run the code its get start from the row one ,and making again duplicate pdfs .

Comment: @Sam Lam Thank you for replying. From `so my request to all pls help me i want only its should fetch the last row which is new. and don't it start from the first row here is the code please help me .`, I thought that you wanted to retrieve the values from the last row. My suggested answer is for this. If my understanding is not correct, I apologize.